# Camera not being released on Android 8.1.0 build version 2.8.4 on M3 mobiles

Tags: java, android, android-camera, issue-tracking, android-version

I am working on a custom camera app, everything works fine. But, recently I have discovered that my application does not behave the same on some devices.

At the end of my camera activity i tend to release the camera and stop the preview.

After many researches, I found that the method that does the release of the camera is not working on the devices that have a build version greater than 2.6.x. The tests were realized on several devices and several android versions. The issue comes from the build version which seems to not stop the camera when it executes the "camera.release()" instruction.

Here's my code that works perfectly on any other device that has a build version =< 2.6.x
PS: I am using Camera.Hardware library that I know is deprecated.

```
private void stopPreview () {
        if ( camera != null) {
            
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.release();
            }
            this.inPreview = false;
            cameraReleased = true;
            onAutofocus = false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me please understand why camera.release() does not release the camera on those specific build versions?

Comment: `I am using Camera.Hardware library that I know is deprecated.` Maybe that's the issue? Also what are you referring to when you say `build version greater than 2.6.x.`?

Comment: @Eselfar, I don't know if the issue comes from the fact that i am using camera hardware or not. If yes is there any way to convert all my camera hardware usages into camera2 API ? without having to recreate my app from scratch. 
By build version i mean the build number of the phone's OS

Comment: Would be better to migrate to Camera2 or even better CameraX from the Jetpack library (`We recommend using the CameraX Jetpack library or, for specific use cases, the camera2, class. Both CameraX and Camera2 work on Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.` source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera)

You'll have to rewrite the camera part but not the rest of the app features.